# HBase reading billion rows

Tags: java, performance, hbase

One billion rows at HBase table available.

I want read all rows and calculate some columns by some conditions.

I don't use Hadoop, I have 3-4 hosts with Tomcat.

How I can split rows between several hosts for parallel reading?

Please write about best performance solution.

Comment: If those `conditions` are functions/data transformations `MapReduce` is the way to go. Let me clarify by saying, `MapReduce` doesn't necessarily means hadoops MapReduce. Its just applying the concept.

Comment: Why are you not using Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use  Salting of Row Key using [HBASE-WD](https://github.com/sematext/HBaseWD). So that you data will get equally split . Same way try go for HBASE Co-Processor if required it can help you